# How can I solve this integral by hand?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{85.5}2\pi \cdot 15.537 \arctan\left(\frac x{25}\right)\sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{\frac{15.537}{25}}{\frac{x^2}{625} +1}\right)^2}\,dx$$
I tried using substitution but I couldn't get rid of the arctan(x/25).
I tried substituting $x^2+25^2,$ but that obviously did not work. So I tried what amWhy suggested, substituting x/25 with tan (θ).

Comment: Please be more specific.  What substitution did you try, and what result were you able to get?

Comment: Well, I tried substituting x^2+25^2, but that obviously did not work. So i tried what amWhy suggested, substituting x/25 with tan (θ). I tried further using his advice, but I got stuck at using 1/(cos(θ)^2)=sec(θ)^2 and tan(θ)^2+1=sec(θ)^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using the substitution  $$\dfrac x{25} = \tan \theta\implies dx = 25 \sec^2 \theta\,d\theta$$  gives us $$\arctan \left(\frac x{25}\right) = \arctan(\tan \theta) = \theta$$

Comment: I used the substitution. Ended up with a sec(θ)^2 outside of the sqrt and a tan(θ)^2 inside of it. If I substitute again, the powers keep getting larger, and I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: I am not asking you to substitute again. You asked what happens to $\arctan (x/(25)),$ and I showed you that under the given substitution, it becomes $\theta$. Note that $\tan^2\theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta$ and that $\frac c {\sec^2 \theta} = c\cos^2 \theta$